# Как скрыть layout?

Tags: java, android

Есть некий layout(календарь) со своим файлом разметки.
При его вызове в MainActivity он появляется как бы поверх разметки activity_main. При нажатии на системную кнопку "Назад", этот layout не сворачивается, а закрывается приложение полностью.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии layout сворачивался/становился неактивным и т.п. ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Совершенно не понятно ни что происходит ни какая нужна помощь. Код и подробное описание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно следует внедрить этот лэйаут внутри фрагмента, и разместить его на вашей активити, так проще управляться с ним. Если нужно сделать какую то кастомную обработку нажатия "Назад", то переопределите метод **OnBackPressed()** из класса **Activity** - и обработайте по вашему усмотрению

Comment: Нужна обработка только для этого layout, т.к. при нажатии на "Назад" закрывается само приложение. 
Если, к примеру, открыть меню, затем из него вызвать этот layout, нажать на "Назад", меню закроется/свернется, layout нет.

Comment: @Александр все таки признаюсь не совсем понятно, не могли показать хотя бы скрин, что за меню вы имеете ввиду

Comment: добавил скриншот в самое первое сообщение

Comment: Кнопка Назад в любом случае будет закрывать приложение, так она запрограммирована перемещать приложение вверх по стеку активити, а есть стек закончился - закрывать приложение. Так что если вам нужно какое то другое поведение активити, в вашем случае сворачивание лэйаута - переопределяйте метод onBackPressed

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, попробую оба варианта

Answer (score 1):

Нужно либо диалог взять, либо к активити применить тему диалога.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: на данный момент это реализовано через onOptionsItemSelected как меню

в принципе, можно переделать и через dialog, но хотелось бы оставить, как есть

Comment: @Александр, создайте диалог в этом onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, попробую оба варианта